# Minimum amount of different tests to be made (combination problem)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

> A history professor who teaches three sections of the same course every semester decides to make several tests and use them for the next 10 years (20 semesters) as final exams.
>
> The professor has two policies:
>
> 1. not to give the same test to more than one class in a semester, and
> 2. not to repeat the same combination of three tests for any two semesters.
>
> Determine the minimum number of different tests that the professor should prepare.

The author says the answer is ${x\choose 3}=
20$, which is the solution of the equation $x(x − 1)(x − 2) = 120$ and its solution is $x = 6$.

My thinking was this: Given that there are 3 sections per semester, there are 3 final exams per semester and $3\cdot 20=60$ finals exams throughout $20$ semesters.

Therefore we should be solving ${x\choose 3}=60$ not ${x\choose 3}=20$. Am I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreaciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The professor gives three tests each semester.  The professor never gives the same set of three tests during any two of those semesters.  However, a test may be repeated.  For instance, the professor could give tests $A$, $B$, and $C$ in the fall semester and tests $C$, $D$, and $E$ the following fall semester.  The professor could give tests $A$, $B$, and $D$ five years after giving tests $A$, $B$, and $C$.  In your calculations, you did not account for the possibility that the same test or same pair of tests could be given in two different semesters.

Therefore, the professor requires $20$ different sets of three tests, one for each semester.  If there are $x$ tests in the pool, the number of ways to select three of them is $\binom{x}{3}$.  Hence,
$$\binom{x}{3} = 20$$

Comment: With my way/calculation, I got $n\approx 8.16$. So if the question was $60$ semesters, not $20$, I would take the ceiling of my answer, correct?  And it goes without saying that I calculated the minimum for $60$ semesters? Thanks for your time anyway :) I understand now!

Comment: If it were $60$ semesters, the equation would become $\binom{x}{3} = 60$ since we must have a different set of three tests for each semester.

Answer (score 3):

Each choice of the ${x\choose 3}$ consists of $3$ tests and therefore there are just $20$ of these needed for the $20$ semesters.